# Add class when (...) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I've this simple code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="required" />

<select id="options" name="options" size="1">
  <option value="0"> YES </option>
  <option value="1"> NO </option>
</select>


<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="city" />
```

**Question:**

I want to add `class = "required"`  to `email` and `city` fields when `options` is equal to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added Id's to your input elements to make the selector quicker:

```
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
 <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#options").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $("#email, #city").addClass("required");
    }
    else {
        $("#email, #city").removeClass("required");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're referring to the extra bracket on the if statement - I just removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$('#options').change(function() {
    $('input[name="email"], input[name="city"]')
       .toggleClass('required', this.value === '1');
});
```

**Reference:** [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: I love this new solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('#options').val() == "1"){
   $('#email, #city').addClass('required');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign ids to the inputs and do following logic , ids are always better as it takes less time to execute in case of complex DOMs.

```
$('#options').change(function(){
if($(this).val() == 1) {
 $('#inputemail').addClass('required');
 $('#city').addClass('required');
}else {
$('#inputemail').removeClass('required');
 $('#city').removeClass('required');
}
});
```